is it possible to write a loop without checking the condition inside, without duplicating the code
This is not the first time I've been in a situation where there is a cycle inside of code that depends on external circumstances.
For example:
bool is_sqrt;
std::cin >> is_sqrt;
for(auto &i : vector)
{
    do_smth_1(i);
    //...
    do_smth_n(i);
    if(is_sqrt)
        std::cout << std::sqrt(i);
    else
        std::cout << i * i;
    do_smth(i);
}

It becomes obvious that you can simply move the condition outside the loop by simply writing an alternative to it in else:
if(is_sqrt) for(auto &i : vector)
{
    do_smth_1(i);
    //...
    do_smth_n(i);
    std::cout << std::sqrt(i);
    do_smth(i);
}
else for(auto &i : vector)
{
    do_smth_1(i);
    //...
    do_smth_n(i);
    std::cout << i * i;
    do_smth(i);
}

After some time, the code grows and errors begin to appear because the need to duplicate the code (and the fact of duplication itself is not much less confusing). I saw the use of std::function/*function as a solution, but obviously both methods are worse then code duplication in terms of performance. In reality, I don't really need this difference in speed, the question is rather just of interest.
If there is no solution to this situation in C++, maybe someone has seen it in other languages? It would be very interesting to see.

This is not C and C++ doesn't have generics so don't use those tags.

Yes, you can move the condition outside the loop. But why?

My advice, don't worry about it.  If the condition never changes then the branch predictor will get it right after the second or third iteration and there will be no branch in the executed code.

Just trust your compiler. It's really, really good at optimising code. If there is something to gain here (and you set the compiler to optimise for speed), compiler will do that.

Template might be an alternative if you really want to not have this runtime condition in the loop.

Alternative option: put common code in a function (or local lambda) and parameterize over the specialized code (as a lambda or function pointer argument). For what you are doing, though, that would be code bloat.

This may be going in the opposite direction of what's desired (who's to say, the question is unclear), but an algorithm that may differ in spots for different situations is what the Template Pattern addresses.You'll trade a branch for polymorphism. But for a complex algorithm with a lot of edge cases, it's pretty helpful.

You could avoid std::function and directly use lambdas, which most compilers will optimize nowadays, so there should be no difference in the end to the fully duplicated version of the code:
auto process = [&] (auto const& is_sqrt_) {
   using is_sqrt_t = std::decay_t<decltype(is_sqrt_)>;
   constexpr auto const is_sqrt = is_sqrt_t::value;

   for (auto& i : vector) {
       // common code
       if constexpr (is_sqrt) {
          // variant 1
       } else {
          // variant 2
       }
       // more common code
   }
};

if (is_sqrt)
    process(std::true_type{});
else
    process(std::false_type{});

The code requires <type_traits> to be included, and C++17 for if constexpr.
You can generalize this beyond true/false via std::integral_constant, but you do need to explicitly dispatch every possible value that it could have. (Doesn't scale well if you have more than a handful of possible values you want to dispatch.)

With template, you might do
template <bool B>
void doLoop(const std::vector<int>& vector /*...*/)
{
    for (auto &i : vector)
    {
        do_smth_1(i);
        //...
        do_smth_n(i);
        if constexpr (B) {
            std::cout << std::sqrt(i);
        } else {
            std::cout << i * i;
        }
        do_smth(i);
    }
}

void foo()
{
    // ...
    bool is_sqrt;
    std::cin >> is_sqrt;
    if (is_sqrt) { doLoop<true>(vector); }
    else { doLoop<false>(vector); }
}

or
template <template F>
void doLoop(const std::vector<int>& vector, F&& f /*...*/)
{
    for (auto &i : vector)
    {
        do_smth_1(i);
        //...
        do_smth_n(i);
        f(i);
        do_smth(i);
    }
}

void foo()
{
    // ...
    bool is_sqrt;
    std::cin >> is_sqrt;
    if (is_sqrt) { doLoop(vector, [](int i){ std::cout << std::sqrt(i); }); }
    else { doLoop(vector, [](int i){ std::cout << i * i; }); }
}


I like this better than my own answer :-)

You could create a function pointer that points to the function you want to call:
double sqrt(double x) {
    return std::sqrt(x);
}

double square(double x) {
    return x * x;
}

bool is_sqrt;
std::cin >> is_sqrt;

auto func = is_sqrt ? sqrt : square; // select function

for (auto &i : vector) {
    do_smth_1(i);
    //...
    do_smth_n(i);
    std::cout << func(i); // call the function
    do_smth(i);
}

Note: std::sqrt is not an addressable function so it needs to be wrapped by a function that is.

C++ Core Guidelines Per.1: Don't optimize without reason
Reason:

If there is no need for optimization, the main result of the effort will be more errors and higher maintenance costs.

As for me, I will use
std::cout << (is_sqrt ? std::sqrt(i) : i*i);

I feel like this might be slightly faster and doesn't introduce too much complexity.

But std::cout<<is_sqrt ? std::sqrt(i) : i*i; is wrong, because of operator precedence, it should be std::cout << (is_sqrt ? std::sqrt(i) : i * i);.

@Jarod42 Thanks for the reminder, I've corrected it. I didn't notice this.

I would just write if (is_sqrt) std::cout<<std::sqrt(i); else std::cout<<i*i;, both because it can be made more readable (if split over multiple lines), and also because i*i isn't converted to double but formatted as the values in the vector (which could be integer).
